# How to finish/kill activity from activity stack (Activity is start by service )

Tags: android, android-service, android-sdk-tools

I am making app for some marketing company .Aim is to show their product to user after sometime(use will select time like one hour and app will show latest product of company after one hour ) .I made a service and schedule with with alarm manager and called activity from alarm manager .Activity will have product information and close button

Issues i am facing

==> Alarm manager trigger service at some random time 
==> Activity Show Fine but on close button (i am calling finish() here). Activity remains in activity stack(it should remove)

**Manifist**

```
 <service
 android:name=".HelperService"
 android:label="Product Service"
 android:enabled="true">
 </service>

<activity android:label="Product"  android:name=".BDriverActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**HelperService**

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("s", 1);
                i.setClass(this, BDriverActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                startActivity(i);
                stopSelf();
```

**BDriverActivity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(1);
        getWindow().setFlags(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT);

SHOWPRODUCT();

// on click of close call FINISH()
}
```

**Alaram Manager**

```
int mint=Global.mints;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, HelperService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(activity, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int i;      
        i=60*mint;
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                i* 1000, pintent);
         }
```

Comment: Activity Show Fine but on close button
How are you closing the activity?

Comment: there is close button so when person click close in onclick ever finish() calls

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line of code in manifest

```
<activity android:label="Product"  android:name=".BDriverActivity" android:noHistory="true">
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: i did  that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Set intent flag for clearing task like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("s", 1);
            i.setClass(this, BDriverActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            i.setFlags(DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);
            startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this hope it was helpful for you

- Done with programmatic,simply by using this

---

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

---

- Or you can done with few changes in  `maninfest`

---

```
<activity android:label="Product"  
android:name=".BDriverActivity"
android:noHistory="true">
```

---

## Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude

start activity with exclude_from_recents flag